# Response body validation using middy

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, jsonschema, serverless-framework, middy

This is the return statement of my lambda function:

```
  return {
    statusCode: 201,
    body: JSON.stringify({item: 'apple', price: 1}),
  }
```

How can I use middy to validate that the body is an object with properties: item and price?

The body should always be returned as a string (JSON.stringify) otherwise the lambda function fails on runtime.

Therefore schema validation here fails (I skipped checking for item and price properties for now):

```
const responseSchema = transpileSchema({
  type: 'object',
  required: ['body', 'statusCode'],
  properties: {
    body: {
      type: 'object'
    },
    statusCode: {
      type: 'number'
    }
  }
})
```

But this works nonetheless:

```
const responseSchema = transpileSchema({
  type: 'object',
  required: ['body', 'statusCode'],
  properties: {
    body: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    statusCode: {
      type: 'number'
    }
  }
})
```

This is my middleware sequence

```
import middy from '@middy/core'
import cors from '@middy/http-cors'
import globalErrorHandler from './globalErrorHandler.js'
import httpJsonBodyParser from '@middy/http-json-body-parser'
import validator from '@middy/validator'

    return middy()
    .use(cors())
    .use(httpJsonBodyParser())
    .use(validator({ eventSchema }))
    .use(validator({ responseSchema }))
    .use(globalErrorHandler())
    .handler(handler)
```

```
const globalErrorHandler = () => {
    const onError = async (request) => {
        const { error } = request;
        return {
            statusCode: error.statusCode|| 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({ error:{...error, cause: error.cause} }),
        };
    }
    return { onError };
}

export default globalErrorHandler;
```

Comment: What runtime error do you run into without manual `JSON.stringify`? You should be able to return JSON from your handler and then response schema validation should be working as intended. The response schema operates on the value returned from the handler, so `body` is already stringified there.

Comment: I get 502 bad gateway.
I added the middleware sequence above because it probably has something to do with it

Comment: I must say also, when I return an object rather than a string, the logs on cloudwatch do not show the error. But when I return a string then the error shows up (validation fails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved by issue by using the `http-response-serializer` from middy.
Upon lambda JSON response (not string), the validator will validate the response body and then the middy `http-response-serializer` middleware serializes the lambda response.

The validator did not seem to serialize the response under the hood.

**Lambda function**

```
  return {
    statusCode: 201,
    body: Object({item:{...params.Item}}),
  }
```

**Middleware**

```
middy()
        .use(cors())
        .use(httpResponseSerializer({
            serializers: [
                {
                    regex: /^application\/xml$/,
                    serializer: ({ body }) => `<message>${body}</message>`
                },
                {
                    regex: /^application\/json$/,
                    serializer: ({ body }) => JSON.stringify(body)
                },
                {
                    regex: /^text\/plain$/,
                    serializer: ({ body }) => body
                }
            ],
            defaultContentType: 'application/json'
        }))
        .use(validator({responseSchema}))
        .handler(handler)
```